# Running tests with Travis CI on Heroku

Tags: heroku, postman, travis-ci, newman

I’m a little confused about how Postman (Newman) tests would execute against a build unless that build is running somewhere. Wouldn’t I need to deploy it somewhere and THEN execute Travis CI?

I connected Github to Travis & Heroku, I think I need to link them in the `.travis.yml` file.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "12.14.1"

install:
  - npm install newman
  - npm install jest

before_script:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - yarn --version
  - node_modules/.bin/newman --version
  - node_modules/.bin/jest --version

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: <HEROKU_API_KEY>
  app: <HEROKU_APP_NAME>
  on:
    repo: <GITHUB_REPOSITORY>

script:
  - node_modules/.bin/newman run <COLLECTION_LINK> --environment <ENV_LINK>
  - yarn test
```

What should I specify to run tests after the build & deploy? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is build stages, see docs https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/.

The syntax is pretty straightforward.

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: install
      script: npm run install

    - stage: build
      script: npm run build

    - stage: deploy
      deploy:
        provider: heroku
        api_key:
          secure: <HEROKU_API_KEY>
        app: <HEROKU_APP_NAME>
        on:
          repo: <GITHUB_REPOSITORY>

    - stage: test
      script: npm run tests
```